# How do I put my map into layout view?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, layouts, zoom

My intent is to export my map from layout view, after giving it a title, legend, scale and north star. When I switch my document from data view to layout view, nothing happens. The view of the map remains the same with no background border, only margins, with the layout tool bar fully accessible.

I have tried changing the layout, adjusting the zoom and changing the margins. The presentation still resembles data view, and I am unable to add any finishing touches before exporting my map.

Comment: That sounds really odd. Have you got a printer defined? There was an old bug when no printer (or an unreachable printer) was defined. Try opening a new MXD and switch to layout view, do you get a page preview with no data, if this is the case your MXD might be broken, if so MXD Doctor might help https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/get-started/administer/using-the-mxd-doctor-utility.htm